# Adding expression to ggplot axis label seems to require an extra character?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mathematical-notation

I am working on a plot in which I have scaled the horizontal axis by a factor of ten thousand. I've been trying to include that in my axis label, but have consistently failed. However, what I've found is that this works:

```
g <- g + xlab(expression(paste("Word Count ", (x %.% 10^4))))
```

but this does not:

```
g <- g + xlab(expression(paste("Word Count ", (%.% 10^4))))
```

The latter throws the error "Unexpected special in...".

Were I to be writing the label I wanted in LaTeX, it would be: $\text{Word Count } \left( \cdot 10^4 \right)$.

How do I get the axis label I'm after without the extra character?

Comment: Your expressions must always be valid R syntax. Try `xlab(expression("Word Count " %.% 10^4))`. There's no need for `paste()`. Or if you really need the parenthesis around the dot, you cay use `xlab(expression("Word Count " ~ (phantom() %.% 10^4)))`. See the `?plotmath` help page for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, `expression` needs something on the left-hand side. However, that something can be `NULL`, so this works:

```
g <- g + xlab(expression(paste("Word Count ", (NULL %.% 10^4))))
```